Why does Rust consider an owning closure to exist for 'static lifetime?
I was considering the possibility of passing a closure that owns some thread-safe value, to a spawned thread. The thread would then be able to call something only knowing the signature, while the contents of it is opaque to it.
I wrote a simple test, and surprisingly, it works. For the closure to be callable inside the thread, the Rust compiler suggested adding std::marker::Send and 'static constraints to it. The first one being applicable makes sense -- all values that the closure captures are Send, but the static lifetime requirement being consdered satisfied confused me, since I assumed the compilier would consider the closure and the value it owns to have a specific non-static lifetime.
I would like to understand why. Here is the code:
use std::sync::{mpsc::{Receiver, Sender}, Arc, Mutex};

fn main() {
    let tx = start_thread();

    // can also run in a loop with a sleep in between or whatever
    let _ = tx.send(String::from("Something"));
}

fn start_thread() -> Sender<String> {
    // Something created on the main thread that we pass to the spawned thread
    //  inside the closure -- the spawned thread has no direct knowledge of it 
    let closure_owned_value: Arc<Mutex<f32>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(42.0));
    
    // A closure we want to be called by the spawned thread, 
    // but not defined there -- this is considered 'static somehow?
    let on_thread_callback = move |msg: String| {
        println!("Got back message from thread: {:?}, owned value: {:?}", msg, closure_owned_value);
    };

    let (tx, rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();

    spawn_thread_with_callback(rx, on_thread_callback);

    tx
}

fn spawn_thread_with_callback<F>(
    rx: Receiver<String>,
    callback: F
) -> std::thread::JoinHandle<()>
where
    F: Fn(String) -> () + std::marker::Send + 'static
{
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        /* Run an infinite loop as long as channel is open. */
        while let Ok(message) = rx.recv() {
            println!("Thread received message: {:?}", message);
            callback(String::from("Hello back from thread!"));
        }
    })
}


Why do you think Arc<Mutex<f32>> is not 'static?

Would it not get dropped at the end of start_thread's scope?

Ah you have a common lifetime misconception.

@goose_lake tl;dr, T: 'a means "T has no borrows shorter than 'a". In this case, the closure has no borrows at all, so it can satisfy any lifetime constraint, including 'static.

Another way to look at it is that T: 'static means that you can hold on to a T for arbitrarily long (by moving it to functions, returning it from the function that created it, and so on), including until the end of the program. This is possible if and only if T contains owned data and/or borrows from &'static references. Likewise, T: 'a means that you can hold on to T for no longer than 'a.

The 'static lifetime you are referring to might be sort of misleading.
In your function declaration, you have F: Fn(String) -> () + std::marker::Send + 'static. For simplicity, we can just consider what does F: 'static mean.
Note that you don't pass the callback via a 'static reference (you have callback: F rather than callback: &'static F). The meaning of these two is completely different: rather than expressing "this reference must live until the end of the program" (which &'static F does), F: 'static means "this value must be able to live until the end of the program (but doesn't necessarily have to actually live until then)". In practice, this means that inside F there must not be any non-'static references. This means that i32 is 'static, String is 'static, but struct Foo<'a> { bar: &'a str } (where a is not static) is not.
Now, consider what happens in your code. You create a closure that captures Arc<Mutex<f32>> by moving. It is therefore not deconstructed at the end of start_thread's scope; instead, it's deconstructed whenever the closure is deconstructed. Note also that you cannot use closure_owned_value after creating on_thread_callback — since you passed the Arc by moving, it's no longer available in the scope and trying to use it will result in a compilation error (exactly because its ownership has been moved). Arc can easily live until the end of the program — it is a reference-counted reference under the hood, which behaves like you have a 'static reference to the value underneath; the only difference is that it's automatically dropped when no longer reachable in code.

OK, understood! Thanks for the in-depth explanation. I wasn't aware of the "value lifetime" concept at all. Feels like a very useful distinction.
